# How to call daterangepicker for several input elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, daterangepicker

I'm trying to use Filament's daterangepicker in a page with EasyTabs, like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/hugons/sKfVV/1/

How should i call daterangepicker, to target all the input date fields? And how can i solve the position issue? As you can see, at jsfiddle, on tab2 and tab3 the daterangepicker, isn't appearing at the right place, below the input date fields?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be daterangepicker rendering in easytab after, and tab2 and tab3 input of hidden object to find the position, so the appeared in the wrong location.

changing the code like this=>>>

js:

```
openCalendar();
$('#tabs-menu').easytabs();
```

css:

```
#tabs-container {position:relative;}
.tab-content {position:absolute;left:0;top:0;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sKfVV/2/

Answer (score 0):

It may have to do with the fact that you're running tabs() *before* datepicker(). Since after running tabs() the inputs will be hidden datepicker() won't be able to accurately calculate their positions and hence position the drop down incorrectly.

Regarding running datepicker() on all date inputs, this should do: `$('input[type=date]').datepicker()`.